# Accepting Data from console and storing it in string to variable of different data type

Tags: java, error-handling, console

```
package yo;
import java.util.Scanner;
public class ko {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        int num;
        Scanner bucky = new Scanner(System. in ); //accepting data
        System.out.println("enter a number");
        System.out.println("you entered " + bucky.nextLine()); //printing data
        num = Integer.parseInt(bucky.nextLine());
        System.out.println(num);
        bucky.close();
    }
}
```

Output:

```
 Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: ""
    at java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Unknown Source)
    at yo.ko.main(ko.java:13)
```

lease help me to find a solution.

i want the input data to be stored as integer for further use in the program.

Answer (score 1):

When you call the `nextInt()` it will miss the input when you call it for the second time. First store it in the `num`, then print it using the `num` variable. Also use `nextInt()` instead of `nextLine()`.

you can change it as follow:

```
Scanner bucky = new Scanner(System. in ); //accepting data
System.out.println("enter a number");
num = bucky.nextInt();
System.out.println("you entered " + num); //printing data
```

Good Luck.

Comment: `Integer.parseInt(bucky.nextInt());`- you don't need to parse to Integer using `nextInt()`. Also it won;t compile

Comment: it was a good point I missed @Amit.rk3. I was answering on my mobile, and I wasn't fully concentrated. Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 0):

It will be what you want if you delte `System.out.println("you entered " + bucky.nextLine());`, you called `bucky.nextLine()` twice, so you have to enter the parameter twice.

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is that you call `bucky.nextLine()` two times, first when you print and then when you try to do the conversion, you need to know that everytime you write a `bucky.nextLine()` the computer is waiting for an **input**. The solution?, first store it in one variable like **STaefi** said.

By the way if you want to store the input as integer data, instead of `nextLine()` method try `nextInt()` it's a method focused at integers.

I hope you understand, sorry for my english.

Answer (score 0):

Try this, I think this is what you are asking for...Happy Coding =]

```
    while(!bucky.hasNextInt()) {
        bucky.next();
        System.out.println("please enter an Integer");
    }

    int num = bucky.nextInt();
    System.out.println("you entered " + num); //printing data
    System.out.println(num);
    bucky.close();
```